# Galaxy Note 10.1 recurring tasks in Exchange: sync problem

Tags: sync, exchange, exchange-tasks, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I'm syncing email and calendar with my corporate Exchange server on my Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet. Problem is when I mark a recurring task as done on my PC the tablet puts it back. This only happens when the tablet is online, so definitely caused by the tablet. I've noticed that yearly re-occuring tasks that originally started for instance in 2003 are put back starting again in 2003 but the reminder date is 2013. When I mark it as complete the dates move to 2004 and 2014. I have to actually delete the task on the tablet and recreate it on the PC to get it right.